# Looping through an id using lapply() in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I have written a function like this:

```
myfunc <- function(data, c1, c2, c3) {
          res <- data*c1*c2*c3
          return(res)
          }
```

To apply `myfunc` on the vector `data` I could use

```
lapply(data, myfunc, c1=2, c2=3, c3=4)
```

But I have to loop through an id along with the vector `data`, so that every row of the resulting vector (or matrix) contains an id and the respective result.

So for the simple case this would be:

```
myfunc <- function(id, data, c1, c2, c3) {
          res <- data*c1*c2*c3
          return(c(id, res))
          }
```

But I cant use `lapply` on that.
I already tried to put all input (`id, data, c1, c2, c3`) in a matrix to use `apply`:

```
apply(matrix, 1, myfunc)
```

But it did not work.

So what would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This could be the data matrix:

```
      id data c1  c2  c3
 [1,] 32 1.12  2 2.5 2.8
 [2,] 33 1.14  2 2.5 2.8
 [3,] 34 1.21  2 2.5 2.8
 [4,] 35 1.22  2 2.5 2.8
 [5,] 36 1.27  2 2.5 2.8
 [6,] 37 1.30  2 2.5 2.8
 [7,] 38 1.32  2 2.5 2.8
 [8,] 39 1.36  2 2.5 2.8
 [9,] 40 1.44  2 2.5 2.8
[10,] 41 1.45  2 2.5 2.8
```

Column id shall get looped through and the myfunc shall be applied on the other columns.
I expect (or demand) a result like this:

```
      id   res
 [1,] 32 15.68
 [2,] 33 15.96
 [3,] 34 16.94
 [4,] 35 17.08
 [5,] 36 17.78
 [6,] 37 18.20
 [7,] 38 18.48
 [8,] 39 19.04
 [9,] 40 20.16
[10,] 41 20.30
```

Comment: Can we have a reproducible example (with expected result)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have data in a dataframe and then:

```
> ddf$res = with(ddf, data*c1*c2*c3)
> ddf
      id data c1  c2  c3   res
[1,]  32 1.12  2 2.5 2.8 15.68
[2,]  33 1.14  2 2.5 2.8 15.96
[3,]  34 1.21  2 2.5 2.8 16.94
[4,]  35 1.22  2 2.5 2.8 17.08
[5,]  36 1.27  2 2.5 2.8 17.78
[6,]  37 1.30  2 2.5 2.8 18.20
[7,]  38 1.32  2 2.5 2.8 18.48
[8,]  39 1.36  2 2.5 2.8 19.04
[9,]  40 1.44  2 2.5 2.8 20.16
[10,] 41 1.45  2 2.5 2.8 20.30
```

Comment: I like that one, no additional package needed.

Comment: Don't get out of patience ;) Just had to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a function, using `data.table` here is an atomic example of your data:

```
library(data.table)

lst = list(id=c(32,33,34), data=c(1.12,1.14,1.21), c1=rep(2,3),c2=rep(2.5,3),c3=rep(2.8,3))
M = do.call(cbind, lst)

 #     id data c1  c2  c3
#[1,] 32 1.12  2 2.5 2.8
#[2,] 33 1.14  2 2.5 2.8
#[3,] 34 1.21  2 2.5 2.8

dt = as.data.table(M)
```

We can proceed with:

```
dt[,res:=data*c1*c2*c3]
as.matrix(dt[,list(id,res)])
#     id   res
#[1,] 32 15.68
#[2,] 33 15.96
#[3,] 34 16.94
```

Comment: Well, in reality the function is much more complicated. I just wanted to point out that there are constants and one vector.

Comment: I do not see where is the problem, if f is your function: dt[,res:=f(data,c1,c2,c3)]

Comment: ok, I got it. Sorry, I just did not get it... Seems to be a practicable way

Comment: especially I you have a huge amount of data!

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally rather do it with an `apply`:

```
x <- data.frame(id = 32:41, 
                data = c(1.12, 1.14, 1.21, 1.22, 1.27, 1.3, 1.32, 1.36, 1.44, 1.45), 
                c1 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                c2 = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5), 
                c3 = c(2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8))
x$res <- apply(x[,-1],1,prod)
x[, c("id", "res")]
```

Comment: That's the way I'd do it

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm being dumb this could be quite simple.

So, you understand how to use lapply to create the vector `res`, right? Just join it with your id column. They will be in the same order so the IDs will match up.

```
cbind(data$id, res)
```

Comment: I already thought about that, but I'm looking for a more elegant way